# mod_deflate and Pagespeed

Tags: apache-2.2, compression, mod-deflate

I´ve activated mod_deflate on my server. The problem is that Google pagespeed says that my site needs a compression.

Have anybody an idea?

This code is in the /etc/apache2/apache2.conf. I restartet apache.

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain text/html text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/js text/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript application/x-
javascript
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to configure Output filter

```
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
```

This is the Mod_deflate configuration i use to get 100% on Google Pagespeedinsight

```
# MOD_DEFLATE COMPRESSION
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml application/xml application/xhtml+xml text/javascript text/css application/x-javascript application/x-httpd-php

# SET VAR
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip

# DEFLATE NOT COMPATIBLE BROWERS
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
```

Don't forget to restart Apache service once the change has been made

Comment: You can remove the lines that account for buggy gzip support in Mozilla (Netscape) 4, which was distributed between 1997 and 1998 and is no longer in significant use.

Comment: It is for the time travelers

Comment: Thanks guys - but the problem is not solved. mod_deflate is definitly activated and I´am on the right server :-). I´am a little bit desperate - because of wasting your and my time for such a problem like this.

Comment: Np ! can you try in shell `apache2ctl -M` to verify all installed mode ? can you check in your browser > webmaster tool > network > click on your page > check header, when you access to your website ?

Comment: Thanks. The `mod_deflate` is installed. In the header I found `content-encoding: gzip`

Comment: So, your trouble is solved ?